# Creating a vector of specific length and characters in r

Tags: r, vector

I wish to create a vector of a set length with the same exact character.

For example, I want r to store:

```
vector1 = [1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Where the entries are the same, and of length 6.

Thank you.

Comment: R uses `c()` for vectors, not brackets.  `vector1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to repeat a value a specific number of times, use `rep()`. For example

```
rep(1,6)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `rep_len()`, which according to `?rep` is a faster simplified version for this type of repetition.

You can accomplish this like so:

```
> vector1 <- rep_len(1, 6)
```

Resulting in your desired vector:

```
> vector1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: With a vector length of 6, the difference between using `vector1 <- rep(1, 6)` and `vector1 <- rep_len(1, 6)` was effectively zero.  However, at larger vector lengths (i.e., 1,000,000+), the difference became measurable, 0.09 seconds for `rep()` vs. 0.04 for `rep_len()`.